# Can I wrap collectAsState with remember when I use Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I hope to  share a parameter `val isCanAddRecord by mViewMode.isCanAddRecord.collectAsState()` among @Composable functions.

The Code A is based the article [How can I share info among @Composable function in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72589279/how-can-i-share-info-among-composable-function-in-android-studio)

I know `collectAsState()` is wrapped with  `remember`, you can see the Source Code.

Now you will find the object `watchState` is wrapped with `remember`, and `watchState.isCanAddRecord` which is assiged to `mViewMode.isCanAddRecord.collectAsState()` is wrapped with remember again.

Will the Code A cause error?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenHome_Watch(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    mViewMode: SoundViewModel,
    watchState:WatchState =  rememberWatchState(mViewMode)
){
   ...
}


class WatchState(
    val isCanAddRecord: State<Boolean>, 
    ...
){
    ...
}

@Composable
fun rememberWatchState(mViewMode: SoundViewModel): WatchState {  
    val watchState = WatchState(mViewMode.isCanAddRecord.collectAsState())

    return remember {
        watchState
    }
}
```

**Source Code**

```
@Composable
fun <T : R, R> Flow<T>.collectAsState(
    initial: R,
    context: CoroutineContext = EmptyCoroutineContext
): State<R> = produceState(initial, this, context) {
    if (context == EmptyCoroutineContext) {
        collect { value = it }
    } else withContext(context) {
        collect { value = it }
    }
}

@Composable
fun <T> produceState(
    initialValue: T,
    key1: Any?,
    key2: Any?,
    @BuilderInference producer: suspend ProduceStateScope<T>.() -> Unit
): State<T> {
    val result = remember { mutableStateOf(initialValue) }
    LaunchedEffect(key1, key2) {
        ProduceStateScopeImpl(result, coroutineContext).producer()
    }
    return result
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to remember a State that is already in a ViewModel? Point of `remember` is to have your objects to survive recomposition or your calculations not be repeated on each recomposition.

Comment: Thanks！Yes, I can share info among compose functions with two parameters,  `mViewMode` and `watchState`, but I hope to merge `mViewMode` into `watchState`, so I can share info with only one parameter  `watchState`.

Comment: But,  `fun rememberWatchState` is wrapped with `remember` by your way.

Comment: I don't think you might have any issues as long as your ViewModel outlives your Composable but this is something i don't prefer. Having 2 separate states doesn't hurt. And if you want to hold a class that holds many properties or states i would move it ViewModel instead of passing state from ViewModel. Of course, this is open to debate. This is something that i don't prefer.

Comment: In my opinion need for having a class with states and wrapping is required when you don't have any means to store properties from previous recomposition. When you have a ViewModel or another class i think having a remember is redundant

Comment: Thanks! I have to generate a coroutines to keep running in order to listen to the change of the state when I use ViewModel to hold State variable.  
I don't know if it will cost many system resources. It's my confused about it at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73105380/will-the-operation-of-collect-from-flow-cost-many-system-resources-when-i-use-co, could you have a look?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can remember your mutableState or any other remember or anything that is not Composable. You can remember measurePolicy or even another code block as lambda for drawing like Modifier.drawWithCache does. [Jetnews App sample](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/c22345b9ffddd69acf365929dc3ffe0c7694be5c/JetNews/app/src/main/java/com/example/jetnews/ui/interests/InterestsScreen.kt#L169) does what you about. This is a matter of preference, you can store anything that is not Composable inside your remember block.

```
/**
 * Remembers the content for each tab on the Interests screen
 * gathering application data from [InterestsViewModel]
 */
@Composable
fun rememberTabContent(interestsViewModel: InterestsViewModel): List<TabContent> {
    // UiState of the InterestsScreen
    val uiState by interestsViewModel.uiState.collectAsState()

    // Describe the screen sections here since each section needs 2 states and 1 event.
    // Pass them to the stateless InterestsScreen using a tabContent.
    val topicsSection = TabContent(Sections.Topics) {
        val selectedTopics by interestsViewModel.selectedTopics.collectAsState()
        TabWithSections(
            sections = uiState.topics,
            selectedTopics = selectedTopics,
            onTopicSelect = { interestsViewModel.toggleTopicSelection(it) }
        )
    }

    val peopleSection = TabContent(Sections.People) {
        val selectedPeople by interestsViewModel.selectedPeople.collectAsState()
        TabWithTopics(
            topics = uiState.people,
            selectedTopics = selectedPeople,
            onTopicSelect = { interestsViewModel.togglePersonSelected(it) }
        )
    }

    val publicationSection = TabContent(Sections.Publications) {
        val selectedPublications by interestsViewModel.selectedPublications.collectAsState()
        TabWithTopics(
            topics = uiState.publications,
            selectedTopics = selectedPublications,
            onTopicSelect = { interestsViewModel.togglePublicationSelected(it) }
        )
    }

    return listOf(topicsSection, peopleSection, publicationSection)
}


   val tabContent = rememberTabContent(interestsViewModel)
    val (currentSection, updateSection) = rememberSaveable {
        mutableStateOf(tabContent.first().section)
    }
```

Remember lambda

```
fun Modifier.drawWithCache(
    onBuildDrawCache: CacheDrawScope.() -> DrawResult
) = composed(
    inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo {
        name = "drawWithCache"
        properties["onBuildDrawCache"] = onBuildDrawCache
    }
) {
    val cacheDrawScope = remember { CacheDrawScope() }
    this.then(DrawContentCacheModifier(cacheDrawScope, onBuildDrawCache))
}
```

Remember layout policy which is widely used with layouts

```
@Composable
@UiComposable
fun BoxWithConstraints(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    contentAlignment: Alignment = Alignment.TopStart,
    propagateMinConstraints: Boolean = false,
    content:
        @Composable @UiComposable BoxWithConstraintsScope.() -> Unit
) {
    val measurePolicy = rememberBoxMeasurePolicy(contentAlignment, propagateMinConstraints)
    SubcomposeLayout(modifier) { constraints ->
        val scope = BoxWithConstraintsScopeImpl(this, constraints)
        val measurables = subcompose(Unit) { scope.content() }
        with(measurePolicy) { measure(measurables, constraints) }
    }
}
```